# How to measure network performance characteristics on two 802..11 nodes?

Tags: sockets, wireless

I have a transmitter program, which continuously injects packets into the network using raw sockets. Similarly i have a receiver program which receives the packets transmitted by the transmitter(using raw sockets).

I will be deploying the transmitter and receiver on different machines. How do i go about measuring parameters like packet-loss, propagation delay and other QoS parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below are some of the tools that can be used to what you are trying to achieve:

[iperf](http://sourceforge.net/projects/iperf/) - free and open source

[Ix Chariot](http://www.ixchariot.com/products/datasheets/ixchariot.html) - licensed and proprietary of IXIA

I would suggest to start with iperf and that should meet your requirements. It is available for both Windows and Linux platforms.